# How can I find the angle of the surface/3D Plane.

Tags: geometry, 3d, angle

I have a plane with equation   3x + 2y + 5z - 19 = 0. With the help of Python/MatPlotlib, I could draw this plane also. Please find the image below.

[image: 3d Plane Image]

What I would like to know is how to determine the angle of this plane?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal vector to the plane is $n=(3,2,5)$, from that we can find the angles we are interested in using [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product).

For example the angle for the normal with $x-y$ plane, with normal $e_3=(0,0,1)$ is given by

$$\cos \theta=\frac{n\cdot e_3}{|n||e_3|}=\frac{5}{\sqrt{28}}$$

Comment: thanks for Reply.  I understand the normal vector of a plane. when what is that e3 =(0,0,1) and why this should be treated as a vector to multiply with normal vector?

Comment: Given two vectors $v$ and $w$, we can find the angle between them by $\cos \theta=\frac{v\cdot w}{|v||w|}$ (refer to the link I’ve given). The x-y plane has normal vector $ (0,0,1)$ that is the z axis and the angle between the two planes is equal to the angle between their normal vectors. Make a sketch for that, it can help to understand better.